# C# ComboBox Usage

Tags: c#, combobox

Google has not helped me on this one..

Say I have a combobox, with the values "X" and "Y".

What is the syntax to say..

"If the user selected X, do this, else do that."

I've tried several ways.. none work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with? That's extremely simple.

Comment: I'm new to C#.. it's not simple for me. I've tried combobox.ItemsSelected.Equals("X") and a few other variations.. nadda

Comment: BAH! I'm so stupid. I found the issue further in the code (I hate spending half an hour on what I think is the bug only to find it's a dumb mistake in another section)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you're using WinForms, the property you're looking to use is [`ComboBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text.aspx).

Something like:

```
if (xyCombo.Text == "X")
    // Do something
else (xyCombo.Text == "Y")
    // Do something else
```

Comment: That does nothing. When I debug, and select the option.. nothing happens.

Comment: Combine with Karthik's answer.

Comment: @PRPGFerret - You didn't provide any context in your question. Given the correct context it would. Perhaps you should elaborate on your question to help us understand better what you are after (or perhaps even what you have *tried*).

Comment: I want the code to select the option chosen, so that I can compare it in an if statement, so that if it is true, the code below is executed.

Comment: @PRPGFerret - The question is context. It is obvious what your general goal is. *What is the specific event that you plan to trigger to tell your program to compare the value of the combobox?* Depending on your answer to that question the answer may vary.

Answer (score 1):

You have to subscribe to ComboBox's SelectedIndex changed event.  Please refer to the below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx

Comment: can you explain more? That's a LOT of code for something so simple

Comment: @PRPGFerret: You just need to add an event handler in the designer and put an `if` check in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try combining the above answers, like this.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Text == "X")
       //Action
    else
      //Other Action
}
```

or use a switch statement

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (comboBox1.Text)
    {
        case "X":
            //Action
            break;
        case "Y":
            //Another Action
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```